# How do you configure JBOSS to allow port 8080 over HTTPS?

Tags: https, jboss

I have a JBOSS server (7.0) running an application that uses ServiceWorkers, which requires an HTTPS connection. I was able to update the standalone.xml and Eclipse launch configuration to bind my JBOSS server to my local IP (I'll worry about port forwarding later). Connecting to [http://192.168.0.197:8080/[application]](http://192.168.0.197:8080/%5Bapplication%5D) works just fine, except that ServiceWorkers won't start because it isn't an HTTPS connection. If I try [https://192.168.0.197:8080/[application]](https://192.168.0.197:8080/%5Bapplication%5D), the connection fails with the browser reporting "unable to connect".

I've researched several documentation sources and can't figure out what needs to be updated. Please forgive any terminology errors - my background is with application programming and networking tends to be the bane of my existence.

This is the pertinent standalone.xml configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:192.168.0.97}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:4.0"/>
    </profile>
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.0.97}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.0.97}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

And the Eclipse launch configuration:

```
-mp "C:\JBOSS-EAP70\modules" org.jboss.as.standalone --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone

"-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.0 at localhost" -server -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\log\boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\configuration\logging.properties" "-Djboss.home.dir=C:\JBOSS-EAP70" -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there in your configuration:

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
```

You'd need to change the `http` port and then the `https` port.

Comment: Oh duh... Man, you stare at this thing long enough and completely glaze over. 

Just for anyone else looking: 

HTTP and HTTPS can't use the same port. To get to HTTPS, assuming you have the SSL and HTTPS configuration set up correctly, you need to use the HTTPS port. 

Correct URL:  https://192.168.0.197:8443/[application]

Comment: I can't even tell you how many times I've done that :)